# Iphone - How to enable application access to media on the device? - ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-3312 "Global denied access"

Tags: iphone, media

OK, so I have had this problem before and solved it unknowingly and now it is reoccurring!

```
"error: 
 Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-3312 "Global denied access" UserInfo=0x169aa0 
 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=The user has denied all applications access to their media., 
 NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=This setting can be changed in Preferences., 
 NSLocalizedDescription=Global denied access}"
```

Please NOTE://I do not get this issue in the simulator - my code for iterating assets works perfectly on the simulator.

Surely this is an easy fix but be damned if I can find anything under 'Preferences' anywhere that assists.

Please halp!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What a joke - Location services must be turned on...

What a JOKE!

Answer (score 10):

Simply go to 
Settings>General>Reset>Reset Location Warnings.

However this won't help your users out but it is useful for development

Comment: I added a post here about how to detect and alert your users their location settings are turned off for your application.  http://www.betadesigns.co.uk/Blog/2010/12/10/error-clclientinvalidate-could-not-send-unregistration-request-to-daemon/

Comment: In iOS 7 this error occurred in simulator too and I managed to do by this way.

Answer (score 3):

For iOS 4.2 and later use CLLocationManager authorizationStatus class method.

it will return a CLAuthorizationStatus enum ( declared at CLLocationManager.h ), you can test the return for kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized.

```
if ( [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized ) {
    // do your stuff
} else {
   // sorry user, you must enable us to see your location if you want to use YOURS assets library
}
```

iOS 6 introduce this method for ALAssetsLibrary class also.