# Cocoa : Resetting NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, reset

I tried using -resetStandardUserDefaults, I tried removing the plist file, none of those really do what I need. I want to reset my preferences completely, as if the app re-installed. Is there a good solution to this?

I tried :

```
NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
```

But Xcode complains. Apparently, it doesn't like that the plist file has disappeared.
This is Xcode's error : 
[image: Warning]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clearing NSUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545091/clearing-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can ask `NSUserDefaults` for all the available keys, and loop in order to removes them:

```
NSDictionary * allObjects;
NSString     * key;

allObjects = [ [ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] dictionaryRepresentation ];

for( key in allObjects )
{
    [ [ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] removeObjectForKey: key ];
}

[ [ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] synchronize ];
```

Comment: Thanks for that : just one question : Xcode moans when I run this code, because it says the plist file has disappeared. What can I do about this?

Comment: Why do you have the plist in XCode? The warning is normal in such a case.

Comment: What about stuff like the "AppleLanguages"? I don't know if you'll run into trouble deleting it or other "system provided entries"

Comment: That's the problem, Macmade : the plist isn't in Xcode. Xcode just complains.

Comment: If it complains, it means you are editing it with XCode. It may not be in your project.

Comment: Macmade : I was able to solve the problem by not calling synchronize. That makes sense, of course. I don't know why Xcode complained though.

Comment: This way is slow in my experience