# OSX preferences file - removePersistentDomainForName has different functionality in 10.8?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, osx-mountain-lion

This code works for one of our developers on 10.7 but not for me on 10.8

working = it deletes the preferences .plist file for the bundle. The dev on 10.7 also has a lockfile whereas I do not. It's not a problem of file access - I tried [resetStandardUserDefault] and that made a new file, but that's not exactly we want to do.

```
NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];        
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
```

I am having trouble locating any info about changes in 10.8 - does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: Eventually it has something to do with all that "AutoSave" stuff... like "Saved Application State"

Comment: Not really, sorry, I only can point to AutoSave/Versions, -- Sandboxing --- (seems interesting in this case), ... may be u can use 'fseventer' to watch what happens while executing your code?

Comment: Seeing the same thing. On iOS, `removePersistentDomainForName:` and `setPersistentDomain:@{} forName:domainName` both cause deletion of the .plist file, but on 10.8 I get no reaction at all.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and indeed there seems to be no info about any changes, also don't get any errors or warnings. `[NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefault]` doesn't do anything for me. What I do currently is simply overwrite the default values to reset them (give `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:...]]` the same input as originally given to `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:...]]`.

Not really an answer, but I don't have enough rep to comment..