# Possibility to create a new folder in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I'm wondering if there is a possibility if you can create your own folder in `NSUserDefaults`. Since I'm saving 10 objects in the `NSUserDefaults`, and I want to easily remove them all I wanted to use a folder, so that all the 10 objects are in the folder and if I want to delete the 10 `UserDefaults`.

I just need to delete the folder. Is this possible?

Comment: You can not create folders inside NSUserDefaults. You can use NSMutableDictionary to save your objects and you can erase it whenever you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to make a folder in order to remove all your objects from NSUserDefaults, here's a solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545091/clearing-nsuserdefaults).

```
NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
```