# How to delete group of userdefaults in ioS

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I want to created the `UserDefault` with suite `UserDefault("MySuite")`.Now if i remove the suite it does not remove all the user defaults values which i have created with the reference with suite default.

I want to delete all the keys in a particular group i created not the all the keys for the app

Comment: Have you tried with below code ? NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removePersistentDomainForName(NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier!)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

Comment: @deepak Kumar show code.

Comment: Well this will delete all the userdefaults

Comment: @deepakkumar is it working or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clearing NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545091/clearing-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: You don't understand my question.This is not duplicate in any way.Don't just do this kind of things

Comment: It means you want to delete some specific groups key,values?