# Deleting App from MacOS but not cleared NSUserDefaults data

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsuserdefaults, dmg

I have one.dmg file, installed it one time and some data saved in NSUserDefaults. But When I am remove from application as well Trash its not cleared of that NSUserDefaults. I want to remove all of that.

Comment: It won't happen without user's permission, I suppose, since the file is located in the Preferences folder.

Comment: But how can delete all data of Preferences when we removed our application from mac system. In iOS mobile device its automatically deleted.

Comment: @iOSDeV, Did you find any solution for this? how to clear UserDefaults ?

Answer (score -1):

You use the code in applicationWillTerminate callback:

NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29653178/2837760